# Validation in domain class

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have to validate whether this value of eventId already exist in mysql database.i have a database of event where the id are stored in event_id. so i need to validate this eventId already exists or not.

**Domain Class:**

```
class Event {
            String eventId
            static constraints = {
                 eventId(blank: false,nullable: false)
                 eventId validator:  {val ->
                      if(val== event.event_id){
                       return false
                  }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use unique constraint provided by grails

e.g

```
static constraints = {
    eventId unique: true
}
```